# Instalar librerías de Power Point sin instalar la aplicación

Tags: php, xampp

Necesito poder convertir un archivo pptx a mp4 en un equipo que no tiene instalado Office y tampoco puede tener acceso a internet.

Tengo un proceso creado que me funciona perfectamente y me genera el mp4, pero solo me funciona si tengo el Office instalado.

¿Que librerías tendría que registrar y cual sería el proceso para registrarlas para que se pueda realizar esta conversión sin necesidad de tener la aplicación instalada?

Existe algún software de pago o gratuito que realice esta tarea, he estado buscando y no encuentro, solo he encontrado uno que realiza la conversión pero es necesario tener el Office instalado.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme en este asunto.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que existe la posibilidad de instalar Office sin conexión

Comment: Disculpad que igual no lo especifiqué bien, un requisito inical es que no puedo instalar Office.